# How to select specific values in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a pandas data frame, which some of the row has one number and others has more than a number. I need to create a label column, which consists of values copied from the rows with one specific number and those rows with more than one value should be assigned to zero.
This is an example:

[image]

I tried the following code, but it does not work here.

```
df["label"] = df[["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", " Column4", "Column5"]].max(axis=1)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this?

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'B': [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4],
                   'C': [0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2],
                   'D': [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0],
                   'E': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]})
```

Comment: please provide your input as text for reproducibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operations:

```
g = df.filter(like='Column').replace(0, float('nan')).stack().groupby(level=0)

df['Label'] = g.first().where(g.size().eq(1), 0)
```

Or a mask and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
tmp = df.filter(like='Column')
m = tmp.ne(0)
df['Label'] = tmp.where(m).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].where(m.sum(axis=1).eq(1), 0)
```

Or following your original approach with [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
tmp = df.filter(like='Column')
df['Label'] = tmp.max(axis=1).where(tmp.ne(0).sum(axis=1).eq(1), 0)
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Label
0        1        2        0        0        0      0
1        0        2        0        0        0      2
2        0        0        3        0        0      3
3        0        0        3        4        0      0
4        0        2        0        4        0      0
5        1        0        0        0        0      1
6        0        0        0        4        0      4
7        0        0        3        0        0      3
8        0        4        2        0        5      0
```

Comment: I used the first code and it returns NaN for the label column. The second code gives error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. the third code returns zero in label column.

Comment: @rayan that's why you need to provide a reproducible input, this works well with the one I added in your question. Please update. Are you columns really named 'ColumnX'?

Comment: It actually works fine. I did not noticed you modified a bit the name of the columns. Sorry for taking your time. Can you please update your answer based on the input I modified in the question?

Comment: I added A, B, C... instead of column1, column2..

Comment: Then use `df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]` in place of `df.filter(like='Column')` in all the codes